# Automated search for dictionary form of German words

Tags: text-processing, nlp

I am looking for either a program (for linux) or an online resource, that accepts any German word in any inflected or declined form and outputs the lexicographic lemma, i.e. the "dictionary form".

An example: Take each words from this German sentence and feed them into the program, one by one:

> Die grünen Äpfel waren verfault.

(In english: »The green apples were rotten.«, but I'm not interested in translations) then I want this output:

- Die => die
- grünen => grün
- Äpfel => Apfel
- waren => sein
- verfault => verfaulen

As an extra feature, it would be really great, if that program could also split up compound words (and declined/inflected forms of compound words) into its components. For example:

- langgestreckt => lang, strecken
- Fußbodenschleifmaschinenverleih => Fuß, Boden, schleifen, Maschine, Verleih
- [Rindfleischetikettierungsüberwachungsaufgabenübertragungsgesetz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindfleischetikettierungs%C3%BCberwachungsaufgaben%C3%BCbertragungsgesetz) => Rind, Fleisch, etikettieren, überwachen, Aufgabe, übertragen, Gesetz

[image]

### Very important:

The output of that program/online resource must be easily readable by a computer program, because I need to process more than 23,000 different words in a batch-process, without any human interaction.

If you are interested in the background of that request, and if you speak German, you can read more details here: https://german.stackexchange.com/q/36124/1487

Comment: Is it possible to add the tag "natural-language"? I don't have enough reputation to add new tags.

Comment: The tag was there but you didn't see it (`nlp`=natural language processing). Added it for you. Good luck!